# In ReactJs, Is there any solution to stop forward browser button after click back browser button

Tags: forms

I'm working with ReactJs. When I complete a form (A) and go to next form (B). All data from form A will be transfer to form B.

Then, I click on back button on browser to return to form A. Then, I remove some data on this form A. I don't want user can click on Forward button on browser to jump into form B to prevent unexpected behavior.

Is there any solution that when I have error message on form A, I stop user from click Forward button? or any solution to disable Forward button on browser when user click back?

Thanks